# Errors when Using Grinder on JIRA 6.1.1 instances

Tags: jira, performance-testing, grinder

I am getting below errors while configuring Grinder on JIRA instances, followed all instruction as per https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/ATLAS/JIRA+Performance+Testing+with+Grinder#JIRAPerformanceTestingwithGrinder-Prerequisites

Errors : 
$ cat project_manager_8/error_xxxx004.fm.XXXXX.com-0.log

```
11/7/13 7:44:35 PM (process xxxx004.fm.XXXXX.com-0): Error running worker process (Java exception initialising test script
        File "/opt/atlassian-jira-performance-tests/target/classes/test_scripts/./env.py", line 35, in request
        File "/opt/atlassian-jira-performance-tests/target/classes/test_scripts/./dashboard.py", line 9, in __init__
        File "/opt/atlassian-jira-performance-tests/target/classes/test_scripts/./interactions.py", line 35, in ?
        File "./agent_project_manager.py", line 4, in ?)
Java exception initialising test script
        File "/opt/atlassian-jira-performance-tests/target/classes/test_scripts/./env.py", line 35, in request
        File "/opt/atlassian-jira-performance-tests/target/classes/test_scripts/./dashboard.py", line 9, in __init__
        File "/opt/atlassian-jira-performance-tests/target/classes/test_scripts/./interactions.py", line 35, in ?
        File "./agent_project_manager.py", line 4, in ?
Caused by: net.grinder.script.NotWrappableTypeException: Failed to wrap http://jira-fm-dev.devtools.XXXXX.com:8080/

        at net.grinder.engine.process.instrumenter.MasterInstrumenter.createInstrumentedProxy(MasterInstrumenter.java:99)
        at net.grinder.engine.process.TestData.createProxy(TestData.java:93)
        at net.grinder.script.Test.wrap(Test.java:100)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
        at org.python.core.PyReflectedFunction.__call__(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.core.PyInstance.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at env$py.request$6(/opt/atlassian-jira-performance-tests/target/classes/test_scripts/./env.py:35)
        at env$py.call_function(/opt/atlassian-jira-performance-tests/target/classes/test_scripts/./env.py)
        at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(Unknown Source)
        at dashboard$py.__init__$2(/opt/atlassian-jira-performance-tests/target/classes/test_scripts/./dashboard.py:9)
        at dashboard$py.call_function(/opt/atlassian-jira-performance-tests/target/classes/test_scripts/./dashboard.py)
        at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.core.PyInstance.__init__(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.core.PyClass.__call__(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(Unknown Source)
        at interactions$py.f$0(/opt/atlassian-jira-performance-tests/target/classes/test_scripts/./interactions.py:35)
        at interactions$py.call_function(/opt/atlassian-jira-performance-tests/target/classes/test_scripts/./interactions.py)
        at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.core.PyCode.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.core.imp.createFromCode(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.core.imp.createFromPyClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.core.imp.loadFromSource(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.core.imp.find_module(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.core.imp.import_next(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.core.imp.import_name(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.core.imp.importName(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.core.ImportFunction.load(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.core.ImportFunction.__call__(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.core.__builtin__.__import__(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.core.imp.importAll(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.pycode._pyx0.f$0(./agent_project_manager.py:4)
        at org.python.pycode._pyx0.call_function(./agent_project_manager.py)
        at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.core.PyCode.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.core.__builtin__.execfile_flags(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.execfile(Unknown Source)
        at net.grinder.engine.process.jython.JythonScriptEngine.initialise(JythonScriptEngine.java:83)
        at net.grinder.engine.process.GrinderProcess.run(GrinderProcess.java:259)
        at net.grinder.engine.process.WorkerProcessEntryPoint.run(WorkerProcessEntryPoint.java:87)
        at net.grinder.engine.process.WorkerProcessEntryPoint.main(WorkerProcessEntryPoint.java:59)
```

Comment: Can you include the python code that is failing?  NotWrappableTypeException makes me think the grinder scripts themselves are broken and that you are trying to turn the wrong kind of thing into a test.  Also the version of Grinder you are on would be helpful.  Can your scripts run correctly when you run them outside of jira?

Comment: Thanks for responding Travis... Unfortunatly I am using this as-is from https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/jira-performance-tests/src and it doesn't contain any version name as well.

Comment: That's not much to go on.  I'd suggest contacting the Jira/Atlassian folks directly if they are the authors of the Grinder scripts that are breaking.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting grinder.dcrinstrumentation to false in your grinder.properties file.
Not sure of the other impacts but I was able to get mine working after this.

Mark.

Answer (score 0):

The last checkin in Atlassian's performance testing git repo was in January 2013, your question is from November 2013.

It appears that Atlassian did not update their performance-testing scripts recently.

However on the page on testing with Grinder, 
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/ENTERPRISE/JIRA+Performance+Testing+with+Grinder
someone from Atlassian says that they're working on the JMeter scripts again.

If you want to look at the old JMeter scripts they had: 
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Performance+Testing+Scripts
mentions two file names, jmeter-test-setup.jmx and jmeter-test-fixedload.jmx 
Googling these + Github leads to a github page with a 2013 version of the tests, by someone (IT professional) called Emidio Stani, which however do not run well with (end of 2014) current JIRA.